# Code Igniter Passing Variable to Controller Using URL Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am creatting a Code Igniter project in which I want to pass a variable through the URL like a get statement, like this: 
url: /site/cake/1

controller function: cake($var)

but when the variable is left blank, I receive an error, how can I get code igniter, to ignore  this?

Comment: Could you post what errors you get?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Site::cake()

Filename: controllers/site.php

Line Number: 16

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your controller, do this:

```
function cake($var = null) {
    // your other code here
}
```

When `$var` isn't present in the URL, it will be set to `null` and you'll receive no error.

Comment: Great - I'm glad :) If my answer helped, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: You should be setting it to `null` instead of `false`, as `false` is an actual valid value.

Comment: @Chetan: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why Colin's answer works:
The issue you had, was that there was no default value for that controller function. In php, creating a default value for a function parameter is done by assigning it a value in the function definition ($var = false). Now when the cake() function is called with no parameter, it will set $var to false by default.